# iOS app shows black screen

Tags: ios, multithreading

I'm trying to test an app I'm working on but the app shows a black screen and I get a yellow warning triangle thing next to thread 1 on the left panel (I forget what it's called) it says Thread 1, and under Queue: com.apple.main-thread. Also, every time the thread pauses it brings up the main method and this

```
@autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([DXAppDelegate class]));
    }
```

I'm guessing I did something wrong with my image views or something... I'm not sure where to find an error log either. 
Thank you for the help
also, heres my .m class

```
//
//  DXViewController.m
//  SpaceShipGame1
//
//  Created by Abdul Ahmad on 2/15/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Abdul Ahmad. All rights reserved.
//

#import "DXViewController.h"

@interface DXViewController ()

@end

@implementation DXViewController

-(void)giveBulletsProperties {
  //  bullets.image = @"bullet2.png";
    //bullets.center = CGPointMake(userSpaceShip.center.x + 35, userSpaceShip.center.y);

}

-(UIImageView *)shootBullet {


    return bullets;
}

-(void)gameMovement {

}



-(IBAction)clickUp:(id)sender {

}

-(IBAction)clickDown:(id)sender {

}

-(IBAction)clickStart:(id)sender {
    isAtStartScreen = NO;
    [self hideStartScreenViews];

}

-(void)showStartScreenViews {
    enemyShip1.hidden = YES;
    enemyShip2.hidden = YES;
    enemyShip3.hidden = YES;
    enemyShip4.hidden = YES;
    enemyShip5.hidden = YES;
    userBullet.hidden = YES;
    enemyBullet1.hidden = YES;
    enemyBullet2.hidden = YES;
    enemyBullet3.hidden = YES;
    up.hidden = YES;
    down.hidden = YES;
    startButton.hidden = NO;
    title.hidden = NO;
    score.hidden = NO;


}

-(void)hideStartScreenViews {
    enemyShip1.hidden = NO;
    enemyShip2.hidden = NO;
    enemyShip3.hidden = NO;
    enemyShip4.hidden = NO;
    enemyShip5.hidden = NO;
    userBullet.hidden = NO;
    enemyBullet1.hidden = NO;
    enemyBullet2.hidden = NO;
    enemyBullet3.hidden = NO;
    up.hidden = NO;
    down.hidden = NO;
    title.hidden = YES;
    score.hidden = YES;
    startButton.hidden = YES;


}

-(void) gameLogic {

}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [self showStartScreenViews];
    userSpaceShip.hidden = NO;
    backgroundImage.hidden = NO;


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: A couple things… Sounds like your app's not "pausing," but crashing. There's probably a problem with how you're hooking up your view controller. Are you using storyboard or xibs? And is the image view in question initially set to an image?

Comment: thanks for the response, I'm using storyboard, and all the image views are set to images... how do I find a complete error log on Xcode?

Comment: you were right, I disconnected all the views and now it runs... I wonder what I did wrong

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like it could have been a number of different things related to problems hooking up your storyboard and its subviews correctly… Glad it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably bound the uiviews to your .h file incorrectly, happens when you try to do it manually, try to use the ctr key and click and drag